# .NET: launching a process with path and arguments

Tags: c#, .net, process

Paths are relative to current directory. I've tried tons of combinations of quoting, unquoting, changing to a parent directory and removing the `..`, but I always get a FileNotFound error when I try to launch a process.

```
bridge_process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    @"../Tools/RunHidden",
    @"../My-Bridge.bat");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a relative directory, why not pass a fully-qualified path?  You can use the static methods on the Path class in the System.IO namespace to help you create the path.

Answer (score 1):

"Current directory" can in some cases be c:\windows\system32 in my experience.

Try this:

```
    string fullapppath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string apppath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullapppath);

    string path1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, @"../Tools/RunHidden");
    string path2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(apppath, @"../My-Bridge.bat");

    bridge_process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path1, path2);
```